# How to import a gradle dependency

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I'm learning Spring Boot. I already declare hateoas dependency and build it successfully. (I use Gradle). But I still can't import EntityModel. What is wrong?
[image]

```
// build.gradle
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

Comment: Did you try to execute `./gradlew build`?

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ Idea (windows) then I use the build button on it

Comment: That does not answer my question. Please try to execute the `build` gradle target. My suspicion is that this is "only" the IDE not (yet) knowing about the dependencies. The setup in and of itself appears to be correct.

Comment: Currently, I use the build tool of IntelliJ, I can't use `gradlew build` because I don't know config JDK for it. My Project use java 16.

Comment: In IntelliJ, open the gradle view (View -> Tool Windows -> Gradle, if this menu point is not present, please add gradle support to the project). From there, start the build target.

Comment: Yes, I already run it

Comment: Does it run without error?

Comment: Of course. `BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4s` `Task execution finished 'build'.`

Comment: Then it is not a problem with java, gradle or spring-boot, but with your IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a surprise. Today, I just open my IDE then the problem is solved.

```java
// build.gradle
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

I tried these command:

[image]

Comment: The problem should have been resolved by restarting the intellij. The IDE is bad at handling dependencies. If it still does not work, try `invalidate and cache` option

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you build the project so the dependencies get downloaded, using the build tool in your IDE or from the Terminal first.

Try importing :

```
import org.springframework.hateoas.EntityModel
```

and in gradle try the artifact `org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas`

Comment: I already build the Gradle and `hateoas` is not exist :(